# Javascript replace help

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use javascript to change a few bits of text on a checkout page for a shopping cart that I'm stuck using.

I got the following that works for the few pieces that are labeled with IDs. The problem is that one of the pieces I want to change is a class, and I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help on getting the following to work for a class? Thanks

```
window.onload = function() {
    var str = "Price per Unit";
    el = document.getElementById('pricePerUnit');
    el.innerHTML = str;
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();


    if (hours >= 0 && hours < 24) {
        el.innerHTML = str.replace("Price per Unit", "Price");
    }
}
```

edit: here is the code that I'm trying to change, basically I want to change the $30 to say $30+$5/mo, there is only one element for that class

```
<td valign="top" align="center" class="unitprice">
<font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="">$30.00</font></td>
```

Comment: Well, what is the name of the class? How many elements do exist with that class? What kind of element is it (which tag)? Do you want to change with all elements with that class or only a specific one? Can you show the surrounding structure of the element? Btw. your `str.replace` function is totally unnecessary. `el.innerHTML = "Price";` will do the same.

Comment: Jason, you'll need to post some code that actually illustrates the problem.  The code you showed us doesn't appear to contain the problem you're describing - which means we don't know what you did wrong.

Comment: So you want to select by class name. JavaScript libraries offer cross-browser selecting based on CSS selectors: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting elements by class name isn't as easy in JavaScript as getting elements by ID.  Some browsers have a couple of functions to help, but not all.  The first function is [`getElementsByClass`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementsByClassName), which is supported in Firefox 3 and recent versions of Chrome, Safari and Opera.  However, it's not supported by IE 8 and lower.  There's also [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), which will fetch one or all items (respectively) that match a CSS selector.  These are supported by most browsers including IE 8, but not IE 7 and lower.

Your best bet is to use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or [Prototype](http://prototypejs.com) that implements DOM queries for you.  If you don't want to do that, the only cross browser solution is to iterate through all "potential" elements and check the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.className) property of each one for the class you're looking for.  The code for this will vary depending on where the elements are placed, which tags might have the class name, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To give you some code to work with (but all credits to [Andy E's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718476/javascript-replace-help/4718591#4718591)):

```
var element;
var cls = 'unitprice';

if(document.querySelector) {
    element = document.querySelector('.' + cls)
}
else if(document.getElementsByClassName) {
    element = document.getElementsByClassName(cls)[0];
}
else {
   var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
   for(var i = tds.length; i--;) {
       element = tds[i];
       if(element.className == cls) {
           break;
       }
   }
}

element.children[0].innerHTML += "+$5/mo";
```

*(Side note: I'm using `children[]` here because `firstChild` might return an empty text node. If you are sure that there is no empty text node before the `font` element (if you can remove it anyway and use classes to style the content), you can also use `firstChild` instead (you can test on the console what `element.firstChild` gives you). [`children[]` is not supported by Firefox 3.0](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t71) though)*

This only works under the assumption there is really only **one** element in the whole document with that class.

Check out also the comments given to the other answers. If you want to select more elements or have more difficult selectors, definitely go with a library.

If you know the ID of an ancestor of that table cell (like the table itself) then you can improve searching for that element, be getting the ancestor first.

Comment: +1, that's pretty much what I had in mind and thought about writing, but that was before the edit that included his HTML code so it might have been all for nothing :-)

Answer (score 0):

Could you use [JavaScript getElementsByClass function](http://www.anyexample.com/webdev/javascript/javascript_getelementsbyclass_function.xml)

Comment: Not supported in IE8 and lower.

Comment: But you can make IE behave! http://robertnyman.com/2005/11/07/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname/

Comment: My favorite source for compatibility: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Comment: @jsumners I would assume that a lot has changed in the last 4 years since that article was written...

Comment: @Sime indeed, see this updated version http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/

Comment: @Sime Vidas: Still, `getElementsByTagName` seems to be one of the few ways that work in all IEs (ok, I have seen `document.evaluate` now, don't know which browser supports it). But what's funny is that IE8 supports `querySelector` but not `get...ClassName`....

Comment: @Felix: I think it's because they figured you could use `querySelectorAll` and DOM prototypes to implement `getElementsByClassName` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282900(v=vs.85).aspx#custom.  They're lazy like that :-P